# Primitive integer triangles

Tags: geometry, diophantine-equations, project-euler

Consider the triangles with integer sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $a \leq b \leq c$.
An integer sided triangle $(a,b,c)$ is called primitive if $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.
How many primitive integer-sided triangles exist with a perimeter not exceeding $10 000 000$?

I am trying to solve this on Euler project. I am wondering what is the best way to go to find the valid triples for constructing a triangle. Of course, you can do nested for loops but that is not efficient. Any pointers would help.

Thanks

Comment: The Project Euler discourages people to share problem solutions, excluding problems 1-100. Downvoted

Answer (score 3):

This is [problem 276](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=276).  I haven't solved it, but the first thing to realize is you don't have to loop over c-from a and b you should be able to find the number of solutions.  Of course, you don't have time to loop over both a and b, but you may be able to loop over a.  I would start by doing a brute force run up to 100 or 250-you should have time for that.  Keep track of the number of solutions for each a.  Then try to find a formula for the number of triangles that include a.  This will probably be based on the factors of a.

Hope this helps.  I did a lot of them, but have gotten less energetic now.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** $\rm\ gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(10^7-b-c,b,c) = gcd(10^7,b,c)\:, $ so a triple will be primitive unless $\rm\:b,c\:$ are both divisible by $2$ or $5$. The longest leg $\rm\:c\:$ must be less than half the perimeter $\rm\:P\:$ and at least $\rm\:P/3\:.\: $ Therefore, for each $\rm\:c\:$ in this range, count the values of $\rm\ b = c,\: c-1,\ldots, \lceil (P-c)/2\rceil\ $ such that $\rm\:b,c\:$ have neither $2$ nor $5$ as a common divisor. It depends only on  $\rm\:b,c\:$ modulo $\ldots$

Comment: The perimeter need not be $=10^7$, it just has to be $\leq 10^7$

Comment: Indeed, but once should able to use similar sieve-like ideas to avoid gcd computations. But there is probably a better way.

Comment: Does it mean that the solution wont work for p <= 10^7?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) which gives you *all* the Pythagorean triples. That should cut down your search space a bit.

Comment: The triangles need not be right-angled.